# why recursion is returning undefined in javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm using recursion to reverse the number. in the terminating condition i am returning the result. but it's returning "undefined". the console inside the if is showing the correct output.

// reverse the number

```
var result= "";
var reverse = function(x) {

if(x == 0){
    console.log("result",result);
    return result;
}else{
    var lastDigit = x % 10; 
  result += lastDigit;
  x = Math.floor(x/10);
  reverse(x);
}
};

console.log(reverse(73254));
```

Comment: because you do not `return` on the recursion lines

Comment: return reverse(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're not returning a call to function `itself` and by default `undefined` is returned.

The solution is to **return** the result from `reverse(x)`.

Also, you can simplify your function like this:

```js
var reverse = function(x) {
    if(x < 10)
       return x;
    return x % 10 + "" + reverse(Math.floor(x/10));
};

console.log(reverse(73254));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not return anything from function with `return` then by default `undefined` is returned. You have to return the function from `else` like:

`return reverse(x);`

**Working Code Example:**

```js
var result= "";
var reverse = function(x) {

  if(x == 0){
      console.log("result",result);
      return result;
  }else{
      var lastDigit = x % 10; 
      result += lastDigit;
      x = Math.floor(x/10);
      return reverse(x);
    }
};

console.log(reverse(73254));
```